# iPhone UI element -- customized or default?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, user-interface

Is the following pull-up to "Set profile photo" below a customized UI element or a default one? If it's a default one, how would I add one to my iPhone app?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Its a UIActionSheet

for Documentation read:
[UIActionSheet](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Basically it works like this:

```
 - (void)iWantToShowAnActionSheet
{
  UIActionSheet* sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Set profile photo"
                            delegate:self
                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                            destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                            otherButtonTitles:@"Choose existing photo",@"Take new photo"];
  [sheet showInView:self.view];//example for using it in viewcontroller.
}
```

For other ways to display it have a look at the demo (link provided at the top) under "Presenting the Action Sheet"

Comment: `initWithTitle:@"Set profile photo"` to completely match the screenshot in the question, though this answer is basically the same as mine...

Answer (score 0):

That's the new look for [uiactionsheet](/questions/tagged/uiactionsheet).  It's a default iOS7 UI element.  In your screenshot, the "Set profile photo" part is set by the `title` of the action sheet.

```
initWithTitle:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:destructiveButtonTitle:otherButtonTitles:
```

[UIActionSheet Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIActionSheet/initWithTitle:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:destructiveButtonTitle:otherButtonTitles:)

In iOS6, it looked like this:

[image]

Source: [apple.developer.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/TempViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH11-SW1)